# accessing props using ref call back

Tags: react-native, view, prop

I am scratching my head hard; trying to figure out what's wrong in below snippet.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

class MyButton extends React.Component {

  setNativeProps = (nativeProps) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this._root.props)) //able to get this.v here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View ref={cc => {this._root = cc; this.v = 100 }} me="tom">
        <Text ref={component => { this._root1 = component;}} style={{margin:55}} onPress={()=>this.setNativeProps({text:'fgfg'})}>{this.props.label} </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity >
        <MyButton label="Press me!" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

basically trying to get the props from `<View>` element i.e. `this._root.props` using **ref callback**

though `this._root1.props` works perfectly fine all the times.
could someone help me figure out what's the problem with it?

**EDIT:**
I am even able to see `this._root` but even not this._root.props.me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try not to do

> alert(JSON.stringify(this._root.props))

instead just do

> alert(this._root.props)

*i.e. remove JSON.stringify*

The reason it's not working is because **View** is having a child element with-in itself while with using **Text** it's not having any child in it.